# How to get that click is in the shape or outside the shap.

Tags: java, matlab, logic

I need to make the program there is a triangle, when I click in triangle message box will show "In the Triangle" and if click outside then "Outside the triangle"

There is code of triangle and to get click coordinates. but i am not able to make logic of that mention above.

If there is better way to draw the triangle then tell me that to. 
or if this work is easy in matlab then suggest me that too.

**Class 1**  draws triangle

```
public class Triangle extends JComponent  
    {  
       public void paintComponent(Graphics g)  
        {  
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;  
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double (100, 100, 200, 100));  
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double (100, 100, 150, 200));
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double (150, 200, 200, 100));
                 }  
        }
```

**Class 2**

```
public class Tri_Angle extends MouseAdapter {        
Tri_Angle(){
      addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) { 
      int x= me.getX();
      int y=     me.getY();
      System.out.println("clicked at (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
      } 
    });
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Triangle component = new Triangle ();  
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ();         
    final int FRAME_WIDTH = 250;  
    final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 250;  
    frame.setSize (FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);         
      frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) { 
         int x= me.getX();
         int y= me.getY();
         System.out.println("clicked at (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
      } 
    });
    frame.setTitle("A Test Frame");  
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    frame.setVisible(true);  
    frame.add(component); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple.

- take triangle vertexes: p1(100, 100), p2(200, 100), p3(150, 200);
- recover line equation for each line;
- for click coordinates and each triangle vertex sign of the opposite line function should be the same.

Java code:

```
public class Point {
    public final double x;
    public final double y;
    ...
}

// -1 - point is "below" line, 0 - point is on line, +1 - point is "above" line
private int getPointPosition(Point p, Point p1, Point p2) {
    // Line equation: (p.x - p1.x) / (p1.x - p2.x) - (p.y - p1.y) / (p1.y - p2.y)) = 0
    // Canonical form: F = Ax + By + C
    return Double.sign((p.x - p1.x) * (p1.y - p2.y) - (p.y - p1.y) * (p1.x - p2.x));
}

private boolean isInTriangle(Point p, Point p1, Point p2, Point p3) {
    return getPointPosition(p, p1, p2) == getPointPosition(p3, p1, p2) &&
        getPointPosition(p, p1, p3) == getPointPosition(p2, p1, p3) &&
        getPointPosition(p, p2, p3) == getPointPosition(p1, p2, p3);
}
```

For better understanding of this math you can draw an image on paper and play with equations.